# I keep getting an error at line 91 that I can't debug...'nodesBWriter.write()'

Tags: csv, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I can't debug this small application. The code is supposed to

- read a .csv
- select data from the third category (tags)
- create files for collecting nodes and links in between the photos and their tags
- write these tags to a file ready to use in Gephi

I keep getting an error at line 91, and at the moment, the notes.txt only reads :

Id,Label,Number
tags,tags,

Not the actual tags. I think something is faulty within the loops however I am not sure how to correct this. I have also considered rewriting the BufferedWriter + Writer code with the method demonstrated in this link:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/bufferedwriter.html

But I am not sure if that is even the problem here. Let me know if you have any pointers as to how to (where to) look for the solution.

```
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Lecture4;

import Lecture3.*;
import com.csvreader.CsvReader;
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author doyinue
 */
public class ReadingACSVFile1 {

    private static String tagsOfTheCurrentPicture;
    private static String oneLine;
    private static String[] myTagsAsAnArray;
    private static char[] firstTag;

    /**
     * @param args the command line argumentsileReader myFileReader = new
     * FileReader(myfile);
     *
     *
     *
     *
     *
     * }
     * }
     *
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String myfile;
        myfile = "D:\\Learning\\EUR - Handling Digital Data\\Resources\\rotterdam_erasmus.csv";

        FileReader myFileReader = new FileReader(myfile);
        BufferedReader myBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(myFileReader);

        //this if for converting the comma into a character this can understand
        String comma = ",";
        char fieldCharacter = comma.charAt(0);

        //csvReader
        CsvReader myReader;
        myReader = new CsvReader(myBufferedReader, fieldCharacter);

        //this if for converting the text into a character this can understand
        String text = "\"";
        char textCharacter = text.charAt(0);

        myReader.setTextQualifier(textCharacter);
        myReader.setUseTextQualifier(true);

        FileWriter nodesWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\Learning\\EUR - Handling Digital Data\\Output\\Lecture4\\nodes.txt");
        BufferedWriter nodesBWriter = new BufferedWriter(nodesWriter);

       // FileWriter connWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\Learning\\EUR - Handling Digital Data\\Output\\Lecture4\\conns.txt");
       // BufferedWriter connBWriter = new BufferedWriter(connWriter);

        //Multiset Tags
        HashMultiset<String> myTags = HashMultiset.create();

        //Multiset Links
        HashMultiset<String> myConnections = HashMultiset.create();




        //start the loop
        while (myReader.readRecord()) {

            String[] values = myReader.getValues();
            String tagsOfImage = values[2];
            String[] myTagsArrayed;
            myTagsArrayed = tagsOfImage.split(",");
            myTags.addAll(Arrays.asList(myTagsArrayed));


            nodesBWriter.write("Id,Label,Number");
            nodesBWriter.newLine();

            for (String tags: myTags.elementSet()){

                nodesBWriter.write(tags);
                nodesBWriter.write(",");
                nodesBWriter.write(tags);
                nodesBWriter.write(",");
                nodesBWriter.write(myTags.count(tags));
                nodesBWriter.newLine();


            }


            nodesBWriter.close();

            Utils usefulTools = new Utils();
            myConnections.addAll(usefulTools.getListOfLinks(myTagsArrayed));



        }


        myBufferedReader.close();


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is line 91 and what error do you get?

Comment: Line 91 is after the "//start the loop", this is the line:

nodesBWriter.write("Id,Label,Number");

This is the error:

run-single:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:116)
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:221)
 at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
 at Lecture4.ReadingACSVFile1.main(ReadingACSVFile1.java:91)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is you close `nodesBWriter` inside your loop. Hence, on the second iteration of the loop, the write fails. Just move `nodesBWriter.close();` after the end of your loop.